React.js Passport.js session and cookie problem
That's my db session also passport.js configuration in index.js file:
const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL);
        console.log("Connected to mongoDB.");
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

// Configure session store
const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
    uri: process.env.DB_URL,
    collection: 'Sessions',
});

app.set('trust proxy', 1); // Trust first proxy
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        domain: 'example.com',
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 5, // 5 minutes
    },
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://example.com',
    credentials: true,
}));
require("./src/config/passportLocal")(passport)

`
I have a route like that:
app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoute);

`
That's my login method in authRoute file
router.post("/login", checkUnLogin, validateSignin, login)

`
That's my login controller method
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred during authentication.' });
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json(info); // Pass along the error message from LocalStrategy
        }

        req.login(user, (loginErr) => {
            if (loginErr) {
                console.error(loginErr);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred during login.' });
            }

            return res.status(200).json({ success: 'User has been logged in successfully!', img: user.img });
        });
    })(req, res, next);
};

`
Also it's my passportLocal configuration:
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require("../model/User");

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        async (username, password, done) => {
            try {
                const user = await User.findOne({ username: username });
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
                }
                const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
                if (!isMatch) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                }
                if (!user.emailVerified) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Email not verified.' });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            } catch (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
        }
    ));

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findById(id);
            done(null, user);
        } catch (err) {
            done(err);
        }
    });
};

`
When I run this application in localhost everything is okay.
but I have deployed API also frontend(React.js).
after login in production I send request to the /auth/test route
{
"isAuthenticated": false,
"user": "User yoxdu",
"session": {
"cookie": {
"originalMaxAge": 300000,
"expires": "2024-05-19T20:21:58.010Z",
"secure": true,
"httpOnly": true,
"domain": "example.com",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "none"
}
}
}

req.user is not defined but in my DB session created

Backend and Frontend are HTTPS also cors configuration is okay there is not problem in there
